# Attempting to make a signal high for 5 clock cycles and then remain low

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus

I am trying to make the signal called ld_tx_data_scope a value of 1 after the first 5 positive edges and remain high for 5 positive edges, and then have it go low and stay low. However, simulating the Verilog code provides this output for ld_tx_data_scope:

[image]

As, you can see above the signal remains low.

The Verilog code is shown below:

```
module test(
clk_50,
ld_tx_data_scope

);

input clk_50;
reg ld_tx_data; 
output reg ld_tx_data_scope;
reg tx_enable; 
reg [7:0] my_tx_data;
reg rx_enable;
reg [16:0] ld_tx_counter_debug; 
reg ld_tx_toggle;
reg [16:0] ld_tx_data_scope_uptime;

initial 
    begin
    tx_enable <= 1;
    rx_enable <= 0;
    my_tx_data <= 8'b01010101;
    end

always @* begin
    ld_tx_data_scope = ld_tx_data;
end
    
always@(posedge clk_50)

 begin
 ld_tx_counter_debug <= ld_tx_counter_debug + 1;
 //rx_counter <= rx_counter + 1;

 if(ld_tx_counter_debug == 5 && ld_tx_toggle == 0) //5000
 begin
    ld_tx_counter_debug <= 0;
    ld_tx_data <= 1;
    ld_tx_toggle = 1;
 end
 
 if (ld_tx_toggle == 1)
 begin
 ld_tx_data_scope_uptime = ld_tx_data_scope_uptime + 1;
    
    if (ld_tx_data_scope_uptime == 5)//100
    begin
    ld_tx_data <= 0;
    ld_tx_data_scope_uptime = 0;
    end
 
 end     
end

endmodule
```

Any help is appreciated.

I use Quartus which has a software called Simulation Waveform editor.  It allows me to set the input `clk_50` to 50 MHz, and it will provide the output for `ld_tx_data_scope`.  So I've been testing it that way.

**Steps to reproduce in Quartus**

1. Download my project files from google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nF_FMn7xCJBifag5QRBkbpPhO-g9yHFz?usp=sharing
   Downloading my project makes it easier since Quartus has a lot of pre-setup steps.
2. open the test.qpf file to open the project, once the project has open in qaurtus you can than open the file test.v by clicking File-->Open option, which contain the Verilog code.
3. Open my Waveform.vwf file by File-->Open and navigating to file. Make sure the option "All Files(*.*)" is selected so you can see the .vwf file
   [image]
4. Once my Waveform.vwf file is open you should see:
   [image]
5. In order to run the simulation click the Run Functional Simulation button
   which is the button at the most right in the image below:

[image]

6. After the simulation runs you should see that the signal ld_tx_data_scope remains low.

7.[OPTIONAL] If you want to create your own waveform go to File-->New-->University Program VWF than after a blank file open right click in the blank space shown below and click "Insert Node or bus"

[image]

Another window will pop up and then you will click "Node Finder":
[image]

Another window will appear and then you click "List", after that the signals will appear in the "Nodes Found" section. Highlight the the two signals and then click on the >> button to bring them to the "Selected Nodes" side. After that click on OK:

[image]

Then right click on the clk_50 signal so its highlighted blue and click on the Overwrite clock option, from there you can set the clock to 50Mhz
[image]
[image]

If your going to make your own waveform file than while your in the Simulation Waveform Editor file, go to Simulation-->Simulation Settings and add `-suppress 12110`  to the modelSim Script  to avoid getting an error related to novopt:

```
vsim -novopt -suppress 12110 -c -t 1ps -L cyclonev_ver -L altera_ver -L altera_mf_ver -L 220model_ver -L sgate_ver
```

Comment: I use Quartus which has a software called Simulation Waveform editor, it allows me to set the input clk_50 to 50 MHz and it will provide the output for ld_tx_data_scope. So i've been testing it that way. I've never used EDA playground before

Comment: At minimum you have an issue initializing *ld_tx_toggle* and issues with using blocking/non-blocking assignments. Also, because only a limited number of folks here are familiar with Quartus tools, you should come op with a testbench and simulate your design in a proper way first.  https://www.edaplayground.com/ is a useful site to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there is an issue in the OP where the control signals are not initialized;  their default is x.  Adding 1 to x is x; Verilog does not behave as expected control if signals are not initialized.

The way to initialize RTL models is to use a reset signal that fans into the module.  The posted code does not have a reset signal.  Is there any other way to initialize?  Yes there is a style that is not recommended because its implemented differently between vendors.  However the post asked about a specific vendor so lets use it.  I did a search on 'Altera initialize signal' and found a pdf with a section that discusses the topic.    Here is a snip of that section:

[image]
This document is way out of date, I recommend researching this to determine if the needed behavior for signal initialization is supported in the version of the tools you are using.

I performed the following changes to the code:

- Initialize according to the Altera note
- Removed initial block (I have never seen this recommended by a synthesis tool vendor, it would be ok if this were just a simulation model)
- Changed all the assignments in the `@(posedge clk)` block to be non-blocking `<=`, as others have pointed out
- Changed `always *` to `assign`, because the `always *` block was not picking up the initialization of the RHS and passing it to the LHS at t=0
- Change the decode on ld_tx_data_scope_uptime from 5 to 4 because the count is 0-based not 1-based
- Clean up (remove unused code with no drivers and no loads, indent, change to ansi C style ports, align)

The design now behaves as intended. Here is the code:

```
module test(
  input clk_50,
  output wire ld_tx_data_scope
);

// locals  
reg ld_tx_data                     = 0; 
reg [16:0] ld_tx_counter_debug     = 0; 
reg ld_tx_toggle                   = 0;
reg [16:0] ld_tx_data_scope_uptime = 0;

assign ld_tx_data_scope = ld_tx_data;

always@(posedge clk_50)  begin
 ld_tx_counter_debug     <= ld_tx_counter_debug + 1;

  if(ld_tx_counter_debug == 5 && ld_tx_toggle == 0)
   begin
     ld_tx_counter_debug <= 0;
     ld_tx_data          <= 1;
     ld_tx_toggle        <= 1;
   end
 
   if (ld_tx_toggle == 1)  begin
     ld_tx_data_scope_uptime   <= ld_tx_data_scope_uptime + 1;
    
     if (ld_tx_data_scope_uptime == 4) begin
       ld_tx_data              <= 0;
       ld_tx_data_scope_uptime <= 0;
     end
   end
end

endmodule
```

Here are the waves from a small testbench on eda playground:
[image]

Comment: Changed the posted answer to make the decode of ld_tx_counter_debug equal 5 so that the code matches the waves. Also changed the clock to look like there is no edge at t=0.  Seems easier to read the waves.